# javafx reopen minimized window via stage(?) method

Tags: java, javafx, windows-10

SO, I have a JavaFX application with an already implemented Tray that needs 1 option to reopen the window/stage minimized by this `GuiController` function, which is called by the fxml:

```
`public void minimizeImageViewClick(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if (mouseEvent.getSource() == minimizeImageView) {
            stage = (Stage) ((ImageView) mouseEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setIconified(true);
        }
        if(mouseEvent.getSource() == minimizePane){
            stage = (Stage) ((Pane) mouseEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setIconified(true);
        }
    }`
```

There is also one to maximize, implemented by the same means:

```
public void maximizeImageViewClick(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if (mouseEvent.getSource() == maximizeImageView) {
            if (ExamAlertStateController.getInstance().getWindowSizeState() == WindowSizeState.INIT) {
                stage = (Stage) ((ImageView) mouseEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                stage.setMaximized(true);
                update();
                ExamAlertStateController.getInstance().setWindowSizeState(WindowSizeState.MAXIMIZED);
            } else {
                stage = (Stage) ((ImageView) mouseEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                stage.setMaximized(false);
                update();
                ExamAlertStateController.getInstance().setWindowSizeState(WindowSizeState.INIT);
            }
        }
    }`
```

A piece of the Tray, with the Open (`Abrir`) option I need to implement and another which only change the screen and the state, as all the other after that:

```
@ SpringBootApplication 
public class Application {
    //private final MenuItem menuItemSelectedFile;
    //Stage stage;
    private SystemTray systemTray;
    public static final URL MULTI_LOGO = Application.class.getResource("source.png");
    private Timer evaluatorTimer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        * code *
    }

    public Application() {
        Log.i(this.getClass().getName(),"Text");
        SystemTray.FORCE_GTK2=true;
        SystemTray.DEBUG = true;
        CacheUtil.clear();
        this.systemTray = SystemTray.get();
        if (systemTray == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("text!");
        }

        systemTray.setTooltip("text");
        systemTray.setImage(MULTI_LOGO);
        systemTray.setStatus("TEXT");

        Menu mainMenu = systemTray.getMenu();

        MenuItem openMenuItem = new MenuItem("Abrir", new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        openMenuItem.setTooltip("Abrir programa");
        mainMenu.add(openMenuItem);
        mainMenu.add(new Separator());

        MenuItem loginMenuItem = new MenuItem("Login", new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                ExamAlertStateController.getInstance().setWindowState(WindowState.LOGIN);
            }
        });
        loginMenuItem.setTooltip("Login Text");
        mainMenu.add(loginMenuItem);
        mainMenu.add(new Separator());
```

The `stage` creation in the `View` file:

```
public class eaView extends Application {
    private static final long ONE_SECOND = 1000;
    private static double xOffset = 0;
    private static double yOffset = 0;
    private boolean ignore;
    private Timer updaterTimer;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        URL urlLoadingScreen = getClass().getResource("/fxml/source.fxml");
        loader.setLocation(urlLoadingScreen);
        GridPane gridLoadingScreen = loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(gridLoadingScreen);

        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        stage.setOpacity(0);
        stage.setHeight(0);
        stage.setWidth(0);
        stage.show();
        Stage mainStage = new Stage();
        //stage.setResizable(false);
        //mainStage.setResizable(false);
        mainStage.initOwner(stage);
        mainStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        mainStage.setScene(scene);
        mainStage.show();
```

So, I wasn't able to to call the `maximizeImageViewClick` function to it - I can by making it `static`, but it calls an `update()` method which contains a lot of FXML objects which cannot be altered, couldn't found the proper `stage` way of doing it (the attempts:

```
stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.setMaxHeight(0);
                stage.setMaxWidth(0);
                stage.setOpacity(0);
                stage.setIconified(true);
                //ExamAlertView.
                System.out.println("foi");
                //ExamAlertView.
                //System.out.println(stage.getProperties());
                stage.show();
                //if (ExamAlertStateController.getInstance().getWindowSizeState() == WindowSizeState.INIT) {
                    //stage = (Stage) ((ImageView) e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                //stage.setIconified(false);
                    //stage.setMaximized(true);
                    //stage.show();
                    //ImageView
                //ExamAlertGuiController.setMinimizeImageView(ExamAlertGuiController.maximizeImageView);
                System.out.println("foi2");

                    //ExamAlertGuiController.update();
                    ExamAlertStateController.getInstance().setWindowSizeState(WindowSizeState.MAXIMIZED);
               /* } else {
                    stage = (Stage) ((ImageView) e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                    stage.setMaximized(false);
                    stage.setIconified(false);
                    //ExamAlertGuiController.update();
                    ExamAlertStateController.getInstance().setWindowSizeState(WindowSizeState.INIT);
                }*/
                //System.out.println(stage.isIconified());
```

) which was only possible by making

```
public static Stage stage;
public static Scene scene;
```

in the `GuiController` file.

Really out of ideas here. Already did read the javafx.stage class the best I could.
Maybe I'm trying to access the wrong stage - stage `UTILITY` to remove taskbar button, mainStage `UNDECORATED` is the real deal, yet can't reach it - but I dont know....

How do I do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [mcve] please .. mind the _M_ :)

Comment: Not really understanding what the problem is. If you need to minimize and "un-minimize" the stage then use the `iconified` property; if you need to maximize and "un-maximize" the stage then use the `maximized` property; if you need to enter and exit full screen then use the `fullScreen` property; if you need to show and hide the stage then use the `show()` and `hide()` methods. Not sure what the different `StageStyle`s have to do with this. Could you please [edit] your question to clarify what you're trying to do, along with a [mre] demonstrating the problem?